# Window Open not working but window.location.replace works

Tags: javascript

Not working:

```
window.open("abc.php?p_code=" + cc);
```

Working:

```
window.location.replace("abc.php?p_code=" + cc);
```

No error are shown

Comment: This is a javascript question, not jQuery.

Comment: `window.open("abc.php?p_code=" + cc);` will poped into new window . browser block it sometime or popup blocker is installed in your browser

Comment: Oh. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`window.open("abc.php?p_code=" + cc);` will poped into new window . browser block it sometime or popup blocker is installed in your browser

Browser block it. So just set permission